# Express a CTE using Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, common-table-expression, arel

I have this snippet of ActiveRecord:

```
scope = Listing.where(Listing.arel_table[:price].gt(6_000_000))
```

The resulting sql:

```
SELECT listings.* FROM listings where listings.price > 6000000
```

I would like to add a CTE that would result in this sql:

```
WITH lookup AS (
    SELECT the_geom FROM lookup WHERE slug = 'foo-bar'
)

SELECT * from listings, lookup
WHERE listings.price > 6000000
AND ST_within(listings.the_geom, lookup.the_geom)
```

I would like to express this sql inclusive of the CTE using **Arel** and **ActiveRecord**.

I would also like to use the *scope* variable as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the CTE like:

```
lookup = Arel::Table.new(:lookup) # Lookup.arel_table
cte = Arel::Nodes::As.new(lookup,
  lookup.where(lookup[:slug].eq('foo-bar')).project('the_geom'))
```

and then use it with your scope like:

```
scope.with(cte)
```

You can see an example for this in the [Arel README](https://web.archive.org/web/20170813135529/https://github.com/rails/arel), at the very bottom

Comment: Trying this, it results in a missing `from`. ie. just `SELECT * FROM listings WHERE` not `SELECT * FROM listings, lookup WHERE`

Comment: Got this working by adding a `joins`: `scope.joins('CROSS JOIN lookup').with(cte)`